# Deploying Nuxt Universal project - is the whole .nuxt folder necessary?

Tags: vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js

I have run the `npm run build` and it has created the `dist` folder in the `.nuxt` directory. Do I need just the `dist` folder in production, or should I include the whole `.nuxt` directory?

Comment: As far as I know you only need the `dist` folder in actual production, but `.nuxt` is needed to build for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked on my server. This might be true only for Amazon Beanstalk...

After running `npm run build` on my development computer, I needed the following on the server:

- `.nuxt/dist/`
- `static/`
- `server/` or `server.js` - depends on setup
- `package.json`
- `package-lock.json`
- `nuxt.config.conf`

Comment: Then, what I need to do? run npm install on server? that's it?

Comment: @SebinSimon npm install and nuxt start

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you need the whole .nuxt folder. Your web root should look something like this:

- .nuxt
- static
- nuxt.config.js
- package.json
- server.js